# mac os x change date format temporarily

Tags: bash, macos, date, applescript

I use ACDSee 4 for mac and the date format of the exif info = dd-mm-yyyy
This makes perfect sense, because I live in Holland and we use this date notation.
but this is getting a issue when I want to batch rename files using the exif date and time, it's the wrong format if I want to order the filenames.

I can change the regional settings to Canada in my mac system preferences, that works accept I don't want to use AM/PM but 24hr format.

And if I quit ACDSee I need to revert back to the dutch date notation.

My question is:
Is there a bash or apple script that sets the date format to yyyy-mm-dd and 24h time format.
And opens ACDSee.
And when I close ACDSee it reverts back to dd-mm-yyyy ?

Comment: You can use `exiftool` to rename your files according to the embedded EXIF date in whatever format you choose.

Comment: yes that works, thanks @Mark Setchell.
I use this exiftool command: 
exiftool -d "%Y-%m-%d %H,%M,%S%%-c" '-filename<${DateTimeOriginal} $Make-$Model.%e' image001.jpg